# maximum distance graph

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have big trouble with graph theory. I just dont really know how to prove this theorem correctly. My idea was to do it by induction but I am not so sure.

Prove that in every simple, directed, connected graph G with n vertices there is a vertex whose distance from all other vertices is at most n / 2.

1)First, prove the following implication: If the above statement holds for every tree on n vertices, then it holds for every connected graph on n vertices.
2)
Complete the proof by showing the statement for the case that G is a tree.

I

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Induction is less useful in graph theory than you might initially think.  Using a maximality or minimality argument with contradiction is much more powerful and intuitive.

In this problem (ignoring the strategy suggested in the hint), you can start by considering a path $P$ in your graph of maximal length.  Then, *yadda yadda yadda* you nominate a vertex in the graph that has the desired feature.  To see that, assume we could choose a vertex in the graph that was further from the candidate then that.  Then, *yadda yadda yadda* there is a path longer than $P$ in the graph.  Since that violates the choice of $P$, the candidate must meet the desired criteria.

Comment: Can I do the proof applying the hint and your suggested way to prove the theorem?

Comment: @CanEner Yes, you could use that proof for part (b) even though there is nothing in the proof that requires that the underlying graph be a tree.  You would just need to add in a sentence for part (a) saying why knowing that the condition is true for all trees implies that it is true for all graphs.

Comment: thank you very much :)